# IPad App Custom System for Client

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, distribution

We currently have an application available on the app store. We have been approached by a customer to do a custom system for them which will comprise of our current app with a few modifications to better suit their needs. My question is how do we go about distributing this app legally to them? I know there is add-hoc distribution but this is really only for beta testing from what I gather?

Any other ideas? We cant upload it to the app store as it is only really relative to this customer. Im sure development firms have come across this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the iOS Developer Enterprise Program: http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/